# Over height dashed line with kpfonts-otf

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, lengths, kpfonts, arydshln

Consider the following example, when using `kpfonts-otf`, the vertical dashed line becomes over height:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\[\def\arraystretch{1.5}
    \left|
        \begin{array}{c;{.75pt/.75pt}c}
            A & 0 \\\hdashline[.75pt/.75pt]
            0 & A'
        \end{array}
    \right|
\]

\end{document}
```

Is there some way to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `Tabularray` package with `amsmath` library, then the output is normal.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    
    $\begin{+array}{colspec={|c|c|},vline{1,3}={solid,0.5pt}, vline{2}={dotted,0.75pt}, hline{2}={dotted,0.75pt,leftpos=-0.2,rightpos=-0.2,endpos}}
        A & 0\\
        0 & A'\\ 
    \end{+array}$
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is not specific to `kpfonts-otf`, it occurs also with `TeX Gyre Termes Math`, `Garamond-Math`,  `Libertinus-Math`, and so on.

Comment: There are some minor problems with this solution: 1) The width of the outer solid vertical line is hard to be consistent with the current font. 2) There is no extra space between the outer solid vertical line and the array content; the space can make it clearer that this is a (mathematical) determinant, not just a regular tabular. 3) The dashed line style seems to be limited according to the documentation (the only options are `solid`, `dashed` and `dotted`), the argument is for configuring its width, not style (but there might be some way to customize it).

Comment: I have added some code fixing the first two minor problems: making the width of outer vertical lines thinner, and I think looks better now, and give some space from the inner of the array to the outer lines. You can control this space by changing the number of leftpos and rightpos from -1 (maximum space) to 0 (no space). As for the third I will look further and if there is an answer I will let you know.